# How to fix: Gatsby build results in css files being merged, which disrupts local styling on specific Gatsby pages

Tags: css, gatsby

I'm converting my Gatsby site from development to an actual build. I've been able to get everything to work in "develop" mode, specifically using a separate css stylesheet for one of my pages.

When I run `gatsby build` and then `gatsby serve`, the result is the css styles for the specific page being blended into (or overwriting) the other pages.

Git repo here: https://github.com/mfuller22/FullerStackProgramming

Page-specific css stylesheet meant for only the DrumKit (link: https://github.com/mfuller22/FullerStackProgramming/blob/master/src/pages/Projects/DrumKit/style.css):

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: url(pictures/photo-1457523054379-8d03ab9fc2aa.jpg) bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: rgba(51, 49, 49, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .2rem white;
}

.button {
  border: .4rem solid Black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffc600;
  background: rgba(51, 49, 49, 0.5);
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffa200;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.0rem white;
}
```

Original css stylesheet referenced from the development localhost8000 build:

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline-width: 0;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
mark {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
img {
  border-style: none;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}
hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
optgroup {
  font-weight: 700;
}
button,
input {
  overflow: visible;
}
button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"],
button,
html [type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring,
button:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}
[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}
[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 0.54;
}
::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit;
}
html {
  font: 112.5%/1.45em georgia, serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-font-kerning: normal;
          font-kerning: normal;
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "clig", "calt";
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "clig", "calt";
  font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "clig", "calt";
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
h1 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
h2 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 1.62671rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
h3 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 1.38316rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
h4 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
h5 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 0.85028rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
h6 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 0.78405rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
hgroup {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
ul {
  margin-left: 1.45rem;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-image: none;
}
ol {
  margin-left: 1.45rem;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-image: none;
}
dl {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
p {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
figure {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
pre {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  line-height: 1.42;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.04);
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  padding: 1.45rem;
}
table {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.45rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
fieldset {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
blockquote {
  margin-left: 1.45rem;
  margin-right: 1.45rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
form {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
noscript {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
iframe {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
hr {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: calc(1.45rem - 1px);
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
}
address {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}
b {
  font-weight: bold;
}
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: calc(1.45rem / 2);
}
ol li {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding-left: 0;
}
li > ol {
  margin-left: 1.45rem;
  margin-bottom: calc(1.45rem / 2);
  margin-top: calc(1.45rem / 2);
}
li > ul {
  margin-left: 1.45rem;
  margin-bottom: calc(1.45rem / 2);
  margin-top: calc(1.45rem / 2);
}
blockquote *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
li *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
p *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
li > p {
  margin-bottom: calc(1.45rem / 2);
}
code {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  line-height: 1.45rem;
}
kbd {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  line-height: 1.45rem;
}
samp {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  line-height: 1.45rem;
}
abbr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  cursor: help;
}
acronym {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  cursor: help;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  cursor: help;
  text-decoration: none;
}
thead {
  text-align: left;
}
td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.12);
  font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  padding-left: 0.96667rem;
  padding-right: 0.96667rem;
  padding-top: 0.725rem;
  padding-bottom: calc(0.725rem - 1px);
}
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
tt,
code {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.04);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "SFMono-Regular", Consolas, "Roboto Mono", "Droid Sans Mono",
    "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}
pre code {
  background: none;
  line-height: 1.42;
}
code:before,
code:after,
tt:before,
tt:after {
  letter-spacing: -0.2em;
  content: " ";
}
pre code:before,
pre code:after,
pre tt:before,
pre tt:after {
  content: "";
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  html {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

Stylesheet referenced from localhost9000 build:

```
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}progress{vertical-align:baseline}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}a:active,a:hover{outline-width:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration:underline dotted;text-decoration:underline dotted}b,strong{font-weight:inherit;font-weight:bolder}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background-color:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}img{border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font:inherit;margin:0}optgroup{font-weight:700}button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=reset],[type=submit],button,html [type=button]{-webkit-appearance:button}[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,button::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}[type=button]:-moz-focusring,[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,[type=submit]:-moz-focusring,button:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{box-sizing:border-box;color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}textarea{overflow:auto}[type=checkbox],[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:inherit;opacity:.54}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}html{font:112.5%/1.45em georgia,serif;box-sizing:border-box;overflow-y:scroll}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:inherit}body{color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);font-family:georgia,serif;font-weight:400;word-wrap:break-word;-webkit-font-kerning:normal;font-kerning:normal;-ms-font-feature-settings:"kern","liga","clig","calt";-webkit-font-feature-settings:"kern","liga","clig","calt";font-feature-settings:"kern","liga","clig","calt"}img{max-width:100%;padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem}h1{font-size:2.25rem}h1,h2{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem;color:inherit;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;font-weight:700;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;line-height:1.1}h2{font-size:1.62671rem}h3{font-size:1.38316rem}h3,h4{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem;color:inherit;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;font-weight:700;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;line-height:1.1}h4{font-size:1rem}h5{font-size:.85028rem}h5,h6{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem;color:inherit;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;font-weight:700;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;line-height:1.1}h6{font-size:.78405rem}hgroup{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem}ol,ul{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem 1.45rem;list-style-position:outside;list-style-image:none}dd,dl,figure,p{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem}pre{margin:0 0 1.45rem;font-size:.85rem;line-height:1.42;background:rgba(0,0,0,.04);border-radius:3px;overflow:auto;word-wrap:normal;padding:1.45rem}table{font-size:1rem;line-height:1.45rem;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}fieldset,table{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem}blockquote{padding:0;margin:0 1.45rem 1.45rem}form,iframe,noscript{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem}hr{padding:0;margin:0 0 calc(1.45rem - 1px);background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);border:none;height:1px}address{padding:0;margin:0 0 1.45rem}b,dt,strong,th{font-weight:700}li{margin-bottom:.725rem}ol li,ul li{padding-left:0}li>ol,li>ul{margin-left:1.45rem;margin-bottom:.725rem;margin-top:.725rem}blockquote :last-child,li :last-child,p :last-child{margin-bottom:0}li>p{margin-bottom:.725rem}code,kbd,samp{font-size:.85rem;line-height:1.45rem}abbr,abbr[title],acronym{border-bottom:1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,.5);cursor:help}abbr[title]{text-decoration:none}td,th,thead{text-align:left}td,th{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);font-feature-settings:"tnum";-moz-font-feature-settings:"tnum";-ms-font-feature-settings:"tnum";-webkit-font-feature-settings:"tnum";padding:.725rem .96667rem calc(.725rem - 1px)}td:first-child,th:first-child{padding-left:0}td:last-child,th:last-child{padding-right:0}code,tt{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.04);border-radius:3px;font-family:SFMono-Regular,Consolas,Roboto Mono,Droid Sans Mono,Liberation Mono,Menlo,Courier,monospace;padding:.2em 0}pre code{background:none;line-height:1.42}code:after,code:before,tt:after,tt:before{letter-spacing:-.2em;content:" "}pre code:after,pre code:before,pre tt:after,pre tt:before{content:""}@media only screen and (max-width:480px){html{font-size:100%}}html{font-size:10px;background:url(/static/photo-1457523054379-8d03ab9fc2aa-331d5a6ade16716d05c281fcd356bbf6.jpg) bottom;background-size:cover}body,html{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif}.keys{display:flex;flex:1 1;min-height:100vh;align-items:center;justify-content:center}.key{color:#000;text-shadow:0 0 .2rem #fff}.button,.key{border:.4rem solid #000;border-radius:.5rem;margin:1rem;font-size:1.5rem;padding:1rem .5rem;-webkit-transition:all .07s ease;transition:all .07s ease;width:10rem;text-align:center;background:rgba(51,49,49,.5)}.button{color:#ffc600}.playing{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);transform:scale(1.2);border-color:#ffc600;box-shadow:0 0 1rem #ffc600}kbd{display:block;font-size:4rem}.sound{font-size:1.2rem;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:.1rem;color:#ffa200;text-shadow:0 0 0 #fff}
```

While tough to distinguish, it seems like the "build" stylesheet has both of the css files merged together. I've deduced this by simply looking for the `font-family: sans-serif;` line from the "develop" stylesheet as well as the `.keys` styling from the DrumKit-specific stylesheet. Both show up in the build version, but not in the develop version, leading me to believe they stay separate in develop mode as intended. But when building the site, for some reason they're getting merged.

This results in the homepage being styled with the styles from the DrumKit instead of the default style from `layout.js`.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby supports css modules out of the box. Using css modules, which not merge your css for all the pages in build but it will keep them page specific. You can import that css file in the respective javascript files.

The only thing you need to do, to let gatsby know whether a css file is a module is by naming you css files like `style.module.css`

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I will give this a try. I did try this before but may have been doing it wrong. Regardless of whether or not this fixes the problem, is this standard for Gatsby to merge css files on build, but not in develop? If so I'm curious why, since I would think develop should be as close to build as possible.

Comment: I don't think it's as easy as just renaming the css file to include `.module.css` and importing it into the JS file. This still results in the whole site using the style from that local css stylesheet, even in develop mode. What I'm doing right now is "requiring" the css sheet if it's in a specific directory as below. But this is what results in merged css files upon build: `if (location.pathname === ("/Projects/DrumKit/Javascript30/")){
        require("./style.css")
    }
    else{
        console.log("failed to load css")
    }`